# Java: Security Exception - illegal url redirect

Tags: java, security, exception, applet

Has anyone encountered this before? It's causing me alot of trouble getting an appplet working. The reason I think it's not working is due to the socket that is in my program to communicate with a server. However, I cannot figure out how to stop it, and google isn't helping. I can't get an exception because the java console for google chrome isn't outputting the error, only giving me a popup after clicking the errored-applet saying that it errored. If code is needed, i will add. Thanks ahead of time.

```
security:  --- parseCommandLine converted : -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
into:
[-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true]
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@acf892
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://voidchar.com/Other/DatRLTest.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://voidchar.com/Other/SharedClasses.jar
security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
security: Trusted libraries list check is enabled
network: Cache entry found [url: http://voidchar.com/Other/DatRLTest.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Resource http://voidchar.com/Other/DatRLTest.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://voidchar.com/Other/DatRLTest.jar.pack.gz with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://voidchar.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
basic: exception: illegal URL redirect.
java.lang.SecurityException: illegal URL redirect
at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.checkUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.DeployCacheHandler.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ignored exception: java.lang.SecurityException: illegal URL redirect
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@acf892
basic: Loading Java Applet Failed...
security: Accessing keys and certificate in Mozilla user profile: null
security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

Edit: Here's the html code I'm using to load the applet.

```
    {applet width=800 height=800 archive='DatRLTest.jar,SharedClasses.jar'    code='vc.voidwhisperer.datrl.main'}
    {PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"}
    {/applet}
```

The less than & greater than signs were replaced due to the fact that it didn't like me attempting to put something with them.

Edit #2: I have self-signed the jar, this is still happening. I still have yet to figure out how to solve this..

Final edit: After many hours of working on this, I have finally come across a solution, thanks to a friend in an irc channel. Here's the general gist of how it was fixed:

- If you look at a specific line of the output: network: Connecting http://voidchar.com/Other/DatRLTest.jar.pack.gz with proxy=DIRECT.
- Upon looking for that file it didn't exist.
- Doing some research into the file type, it's a pack200 jar which can be made using a jar and then doing the following with it: opening up cmd, and typing 'pack200 example.jar.pack.gz [JarLocation]'.
- Now, replace example.jar with the name of your jar file but leave the .pack.gz there.
- Now, upload that file to the same directory as the applet and attempt to load the applet up again.

**NOTE: Make sure the applet is signed!!** Hope this helps others solve the problem I had.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem with http://www.ol-in-berlin.de/gadget/reitti.jar, when the client updated to java 7. Disabling java next generation plug-in on the client side was a first (bad) solution. Luckily I found this post of yours and providing the .pack.gz file works. Thanks for sharing it. (Maybe you should have posted it as a self-answer) Now if anybody could provide a detailed explanation, why this is happening, that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Your applet is violating the "Same-Origin" restriction, which is a default Applet security restriction that is designed to protect the user against nasty applets.

See [this blog post](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/10/java-applet-same-origin-policy-bypass-via-http-redirect/) for an explanation of the restriction, and why it is enforced.

---

What can you do about it?  The best thing would be to reengineer you applet and / or services so that the redirect was either removed entirely, or it redirected to a URL that didn't violate the restriction.  If that is not an option, you will need to make your applet a "trusted applet"; e.g. see [this tutorial](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html) to understand the issues.

---

**UPDATE**

I am wrong about making the applet a trusted applet.  It won't help.  I looked at the OpenJDK source code ([here](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/deploy/net/HttpUtils.java.html), and [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java.html)), and it appears that the "same-origin" security check is performed irrespective of the security policy.  (Look for the code that throws the exception with that message ...)

So your only option is to serve the applet from the same host and port as the web page that links to it.  In other words, don't violate the "same-origin" rule.

Comment: I self-signed the applet. It still won't load. And all of the classes are on the same server as the page trying to load it. I added the html code i'm using to the orignal post.

Comment: The only thing that could be remotely causing this is my applet connecting to a remote ip via socketing... and I can't do much to fix that? I'm pretty sure both of the .jar files it's trying to acess are on the same webserver, unless it's trying to access it from somewhere other than the one in the directory

Comment: Is there any easy way to diagnose what line the error is coming from, because looking at the stack trace, it doesn't state where the exception is coming from, making it a bit cumbersome to figure out where exactly the error comes from.

Comment: You are probably seeing no source line numbers in the stacktrace because your JRE's "rt.jar" file was built without debug information.  However, if you look at the source code it is clear that there is only one place in that class where the exception *could* be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

As far as my research went this problem is caused whenever java requests the applet and gets a HTTP 300 response. First of all java will try to load the compressed version of the applet, that is e.g. "yourjarfile.jar.pack.gz". If the server delivers a HTTP 404 everything works as expected. But if the server delivers a HTTP 300 response java assumes that there is a redirection target and fails if there is none set.

From my experience you can do the following things to fix the issue on the server side:

1. If your applet consists of a single jar file and no data is loaded afterwards you can compress your applet with the pack200 tool and replace the original jar with the new file. Ensure the .pack.gz file extension is attached to the original file.
2. If you have got an apache and complete control over your server you can uninstall mod_speling. Be sure this is ok for the rest of the environment you're runnning.
3. If you can use .htaccess files you can disable spell checking for the folder the applet gets loaded from. For this purpose create a .htaccess file with the content "CheckSpelling off". If there is already a .htaccess file present simply add this line to it.

I hope this helps some people out.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely violating the sandbox policy of your java applet environment. You do not have the credentials required to do whtever it is you want to do, and you didn't ask the user if it was alright, so the environment killed you.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/step1.html

Comment: I added the exception which i finally got to pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same problem on a customer's server when using Java 1.7.0_09. If I used an earlier version of Java then there was no problem. If I ran the same Applet on a different server then no problem.

I finally found a fix. I cleared my Java cache. (This is different than the browser cache.)

On Windows 7 you can:

1. Launch the Java Control Panel,
2. click "General" tab,
3. under "Temporary Internet Files" click "Settings",
4. click "Delete Files",
5. select only "Cached Applications and Applets" and hit OK.

It took almost a minute to clear my Java cache.

Then everything worked fine.